# adding/removing a item in select onclick

Tags: javascript, select, append

Brain hurting from trying to understand why I cannot remove an item from a select.
When I add a new field to a form, I add a reference of this field in a select.
But if I remove a field, I can't remove this added reference in the select. 
I want to add and remove three things on clicked. Almost everything works. I just can't remove the content of the third wrapper.
Please help... 
Here is what my script looks like:

```
var max_fields      = 22;
var wrapper1         = $(".input_fields_wrap1"); 
var wrapper2         = $(".input_fields_wrap2"); 
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button");
var remove_button   = $(".remove_field_button");
var wrapperListaAutores  = $(".input_fields_wrapAutores");



$(add_button).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var total_fields1 = wrapper1[0].childNodes.length;
    var total_fields2 = wrapper2[0].childNodes.length;

    var optAutores = document.getElementById("Autores");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = wrapper1[0].childNodes.length + 1; //this was the form I found to number the new element in the select.


    if(total_fields1 < max_fields){
        $(wrapper1).append('<li><textarea rows="1" style="width: 90%" id="textArea" placeholder="Adicione aqui o nome do autor do autor!"></textarea> </li>');
        $(wrapper2).append('<textarea rows="1" style="width: 90%" id="textArea" placeholder="Adicione aqui a filiação do autor!"></textarea>');
        $(wrapperListaAutores).append(optAutores.add(option));

      }
    });


$(remove_button).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var total_fields1 = wrapper1[0].childNodes.length;

    if(total_fields1>1){
        wrapper1[0].childNodes[total_fields1-1].remove();
        wrapper2[0].childNodes[total_fields1-1].remove();
        wrapperListaAutores[0].childNodes[total_fields1-1].remove();


    }
});
```

Why do the first two add/remove from wrappers work perfectly.. And the add in the third wrap works, but I just can't remove the added element from the third wrap when I click "remove_button"?

Comment: I would console.log the wrappers and compare them, I have a feeling the wrap you're trying to remove might need a deeper or different reference.

Comment: You are right.. The console.log of the wrappers does render something different. It appears as "w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]". Any suggestion of how to make a different reference? My ref for al the wrappers was to the div.. This specific problematic div is inside a select: <select id="Autores">
        <option>1</option>
       <div class="input_fields_wrapAutores">          
       </div>
       </select>

Comment: I got this that solved it !!!!  thanks alot!!! var myselect=document.getElementById("sample")
myselect.remove(myselect.length-1)

Comment: Glad to see it, good luck!